# React lifecycle / architecture and firebase auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, firebase-authentication

Got a component did mount function.

```
componentDidMount() {
    const {onSignedIn} = this.props;

    auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
            onSignedIn(user);
        }
    });
}
```

Basically it checks to see if firebase has a valid login session and if so logs that user in. Simple.

Now the issue I have is I have various protected routes set up that you can only access if you are logged in.

If you navigate to these via the links in the app everything works perfectly
However if you try to go directly to one of these routes via the address bar then weird stuff happens. Basically it reloads the page, user is logged out so the route (correctly) redirects you to the sign in page and then the above method runs and logs you in.

The issue is the component only mounts once, so when you navigate around in-app there is no remount and everything works. If you refresh the page the or use the address bar then the above happens.

It's more of an architectural issue than a code issue but I'm not sure how best to fix it.

Comment: With the fact, your app is relying on the Firebase API call to check, as it is explained the FB docs you're not actually saving the logged in state in the app, or are you? If your not when your Single Page Application (SPA) refreshes, you're losing all state. You could either set a permissions object in local storage that can be checked or you can bring the user logged in API-call higher up your React app so it runs at the highest level.

Comment: I'm using the firebase auth persistence method to store the token in the session. Firebase `onAuthStateChanged` is then checking for this token and signing the user in. All this happens after the render method has run however which is part of the issue.

The render method runs, the user isn't signed in, user gets redirected sign in page, then `onAuthStateChanged` runs and user is signed in

Comment: Yeah, I get this, which is why your app still needs to be aware of what is happen if the session changes. Saving this in local to save on API calls or pulling the API call higher up your component chain should work.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm not explaining myself very well. Basically, you're saying the component that runs componentDidMount logged in check is not running in some cases, you could possibly prevent this by having the logged in check in your apps index.js where you render the App component, this compo re-renders every time.

Comment: It's not you, the issue is not an easy one to describe unfortunately.

So the issue isn't that the check is not running in some cases, it's running everytime it's needed.

The issue is I have a protected route that checks to see if a user is logged in, if a user is not logged in it redirects to login page.

The problem is the route is rendered, the sign in check is done and the app redirected to sign in page _before_ the `componentDidMount` method is run.

So by the time the user _**is**_ logged in the app has already decided they _are **not**_ logged in and redirected to sign in page.